# Android emulator can't find the wayland QT plugin

Tags: android-emulator

Trying to run the Android emulator on Wayland (Fedora 30) gives me the following error:

```
statvfs('/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_29.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/user/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:66: Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/user/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" ((null):0, (null))
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Even if the AndroidEmulator is involved this is more a Linux/Wayland, problem. You should better ask this question on a Linux related StackExchange site or forum.

Answer (score 2):

To debug this issue, start the emulator on the command line. For example:

```
~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30
```

(To list all available AVDs, use `emulator -list-avds`.)

In your case, you have probably set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` env variable, but Android Studio seems to bundle their own platform plugins,
which don't include wayland, only xcb. This results in the following error message:

```
...
INFO    | Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/username/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" ((null):0, (null))
...
```

This works for me:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30
```